# Pretty-print my BQN Arrays

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

[Marshall Lochbaum's online BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html) has an interesting(and aesthetically pleasing) method of displaying arrays. Your task is to implement a version with simpler rules.

```
[2,[3],4,[[[6,[5],7]]]]
```

becomes:

```
┌─                                 
· 2 ┌·    4 ┌·                     
    · 3     · ┌·                   
        ┘     · ┌─                 
                · 6 ┌·    7        
                    · 5            
                        ┘          
                            ┘      
                              ┘    
                                ┘  
                                  ┘
```

### Rules for drawing

- A singleton array has

```
┌· 
·
```

as its top left corner.

- A non-singleton array has

```
┌─  
·
```

as its top left corner.

(In the actual BQN, this is used for rank-0, or "unit" arrays)

- All arrays have

```
┘
```

as their bottom right corner.

- Each element at a certain depth will be displayed at the same depth vertically.
  For example, 2 and 4 are displayed 1 unit from the top since they are at depth 1.
- Each further level of nesting depth moves 1 unit down in depth.
- Numbers next to each other will be separated by a single space.

### Other details

- You may take a ragged numeric array in any way your language supports.
- The input will only consist of integers and nested arrays containing integers.
- If your language does not support arrays with depth, you may take a string/other equivalent that your language supports.
- If your language's codepage does not contain the characters `┌ · ─ ┘`, you can count them as 1 byte.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in each language wins.
- Since bacon strips are thin, your code must be thin and small as well.

Comment: Nice challenge, though I feel like "Take a nested array, and 'pull down' elements one line for each depth of nest", with none of the special character requirements, might be the purer form of it.

Comment: @Jonah That is a good idea. I'll sandbox it.

Comment: I realized you'd still need a way to show arrays ending -- eg, if you had two adjacent nested arrays.  That could be printed on the same line though.

Comment: @Jonah seems like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6600/80214) is the exact same idea, except upside down.

Comment: Yeah it’s too close

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 72 bytes

```
ＦＳ≡ι(«⊞υⅉＰ⌈┌´·↘→⊞υⅉ»)«≔⊕⊟υιＭ¹⁻ιⅉ┘Ｍ⁻ⅉ⊟υ↑¿υ⊞υ⌈⟦ι⊟υ⟧»,«↑≔ＫＤ⊕ⅈ←ι§≔ι⊖⌕ι┌¦─↘»ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZG9asMwEMfn@CkOTydQh36DOwVMIdCAaSm0lA7GluOjjmwsKQmUQMcOGTv0Tbr3UfIijmTloxm66e7@97/fnbIybbM6rbquqFvAkWyMftAtyQkyBmpOOisBicF7kKVKQIhhZN@DxKgSDYdnK7sJBmNTaWpsm8ZovfrkEK6/Vr8/YV@rZwKjuJ7Le5qU@pDah8dmy@0k5icNlaKJtGRZK6ZCapFjUjdoGONAe7NTDmOSRiF5m96257Ek3wcOL7IKDnuX6LFxdSrAxrCDGacLmpopvtBO@vqXjns6v4k32JImQrzF1IpMU33M/YT9uDtR6B287xnqkczFwsHH4qC/JZm7nDtm6Frt4@Ofmy6DXBSp/YYI/N7Oftl1eMbxnPELjohXHC8Zv7bXYd3JrNoA) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses lists rather than arrays because they're easier to input. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ≡ι
```

Switch over each character of the input as a string.

```
(«
```

For a `(`, ...

```
⊞υⅉ
```

... save the vertical position as the top margin, ...

```
Ｐ⌈┌´·↘→
```

... assume a single-element list, ...

```
⊞υⅉ
```

... and save the vertical position again, this time as the bottom margin.

```
»)«
```

For a `)`, ...

```
≔⊕⊟υι
```

... get the bottom margin of this list, plus 1, ...

```
Ｍ¹⁻ιⅉ
```

... move to that row, ...

```
┘
```

... close the list, ...

```
Ｍ⁻ⅉ⊟υ↑
```

... move to and forget the top margin of this list, ...

```
¿υ⊞υ⌈⟦ι⊟υ⟧
```

... and update the bottom margin of the containing list if necessary.

```
»,«
```

For a `,`, ...

```
↑≔ＫＤ⊕ⅈ←ι
```

... grab the text on the previous row, ...

```
§≔ι⊖⌕ι┌¦─
```

... find the `┌` and change the character after it to a `─`, ...

```
↘
```

... and move to the next column on the original row.

```
»ι
```

Otherwise, just output the current character.

Note that the `·` is in Charcoal's code page (so because it needs to be quoted it ends up costing me two bytes!) but the box-drawing characters are not. They would normally cost three bytes in Charcoal so as I use them four times I have subtracted 8 bytes from Charcoal's calculation.